# How to group REST API in micronaut?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, micronaut

I use Micronaut @Version to implement my REST API Versioning strategy, and I use header X-API-VERSION to carry the version number, but I don't know how to group different version of REST API endpoints with Micronaut-openapi. I can do that in SprintBoot by customizing GroupedOpenApi, but I cannot do that in micronaut. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks.